# zoom does not work in ie11 but perfect in chrome

Tags: javascript, zooming

my code is

```
var defaultWidth = 6142;
var userWidth = window.innerWidth;
var userHeight = window.innerHeight;
var scalcNum = userWidth / defaultWidth;
if ( scalcNum < 1 ) {
    scalcNum = scalcNum*100;
    var rootElement = document.documentElement;
    var setHeight = userHeight/(scalcNum/100);
    rootElement.style.zoom = scalcNum + "%";
    rootElement.style.height = setHeight+"px";
}
```

if I use document.body it's work but doesn't look  as good as in chrome,so why?

I just wanna zoom can work like chrome in ie11, help and thx